# Cross-Origin request blocked

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the module GMap but am having an issue with the maps that are generated on my drupal site.

I click the pin, and all I get is "Loading..." and the following error pops up in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://map/node/load/11/0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I have yet to find an example of someone coming across this issue, so I'd appreciate any help.

---

EDIT - I know the issue might revolve around the "remote resource" obviously it is trying to pull it from http://history.arvadahistory.org/map/node/load/11/0 rather than just http://map/node/load/11/0. Is there something I might be missing from the configuration?

Comment: Is history.arvadahistory.org the site that's requesting the maps _and_ the site that's hosting them?

Comment: Yes Clive, they're on the same Drupal site.